# Python decrypting data of recvfrom

Tags: python-3.x, recvfrom

I'm currently building a sort of sniffer for a video game(Albion Online).
I used the recvfrom method and I get something like that :

```
bE\x00\x00k\ry\x00\x00l\x11\xfct\x05\xbc}\x17\xc0\xa8\x01\x19\x13\xc0\xdeC\x00W\xce\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x01\x1d__\xd8\x0cIhN\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00\xd3\x00\x003\xc8\xf3\x04\x03\x00\x02\x00l\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x019\x01x\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x03\xc8\xcb\xb8x\x1e\x8c\xda\x08Fs~C\xb6\xf6p\xc3\xb1\x00\x00@@z\x85wC/\xb5s\xc3
```

I have no idea what to do with that to make it a readable format (dictionnary? maybe).

Thanks for you help !

Amg1n3

Comment: If you don't know what format the data is in, you're going to have to find documentation or do some reverse engineering.

Comment: Any idea what kind of format this could be in ?

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea.  You haven't even given the title of the game, so it's anybody's guess unless they can read hex.